# Cannot start rofi

Tags: i3, rofi, endeavouros

getting this error after I updated by system yesterday, running endevouros i3 flavor.

```
The following errors where detected when starting rofi:

Failed to set binding Tab for: Go to next element (in logical order).(kb-element-next):
     there is always a binding matching 'Tab'
Failed to set binding ISO_LEFT_Tab for: Go to next element (in logical order).(kb-element-prev):
     there is already a binding matching 'ISO_LEFT_Tab'
```

I am guess this means I have tab and iso_left_tab set to some config value twice, but I can't seems to see where it is, or this error pointing to something else?

My rofi config file : https://gist.github.com/SaHHiiLL/23c43c72fba344842ffd306155d60620

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest update detects duplicate key bindings and will prevent `rofi` from starting.

The duplicate bindings are:

```
kb-mode-previous: "Shift+Left,Control+ISO_Left_Tab";
...
kb-row-up: "Up,Control+p,ISO_Left_Tab";
...
kb-row-tab: "Tab";
```

Remove `ISO_Left_Tab` from `kb-row-up` and remove or comment `kb-row-tab: "Tab";`.

Comment: life-saver. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works.